# ng-click not working within directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the directive with the function that is supposed to be called when  clicked.

```
    ebApp.directive('monthDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'htmlFiles/monthDirective.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            ebObj: "=obj"
        },
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.removeDir = function (removeVal) {
                console.log("asd"); //not showing in the console

            }
            console.log(scope);
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {

        }
    }
})
```

The ng-click in the following directive is not working. The directive's html

```
    <div class="row monthDirC">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign pull-right cursorC" 
  ng-click="removeDir(ebObj.costArray[count])" ></span>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="datepick" class="col-md-6">Select month</label>
        <md-datepicker id="datepick" class="col-md-6" ng-model="ebObj.costArray[count].myDate"
                       md-placeholder="Enter date"
                       md-min-date="minDate"
                       md-max-date="maxDate">

        </md-datepicker>
    </div>
```

The html that uses the directive:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <month-dir ng-transclude ng-repeat="count in ebObj.costArray[0].countArray" obj="ebObj.costArray[count+1]"></month-dir>
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing function name link in : function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){ -> link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){

Comment: @WasifKhan. tried it. didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working correctly. Make sure you don't have any errors. Try this,

```js
var ebApp = angular.module('ebApp', []);

ebApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ebObj = 'someVal';
});

ebApp.directive('monthDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-click="removeDir()"><b>Click Me</b><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            ebObj: '=obj'
        },
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.removeDir = function (removeVal) {
                console.log('asd'); //not showing in the console
            }
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {

        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ebApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <month-dir ebObj="ebObj"><i>Click Me!</i></month-dir>
</div>
```

Comment: what could be wrong in my template with the directive. it's not working when i use the templateurl

Comment: I added a $watch on an input field in the  directive. that didnt work either

Comment: i edited the code in the answer. try removing the `ng-transclude` from the html and place it inside the template

Comment: i edited the answer for better understanding. generally we use `ng-transclude` for binding the innerHTML value in the directive. You can refer more on [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude).